# How to enter password text string in Host.UI.PromptForCredential Powershell Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to create a custom task in Windows task scheduler using powershell.

I have created a script that will open a UIBox with two input fields.

```
1. user field
2. password field
```

I am able to automatically insert text into the `1. user field` box when the box is generated but am having trouble finding a way to insert my password into the `2. password field.`.

Any idea's on how I can insert my password automatically?

Below is full script so far.

```
$jobname = 'start_ahk_multiple_hotkeys'
$script = '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file C:\script.ps1'
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute '"C:\Program Files\AHK\AutoHotkey.exe"' -Argument '%OneDrive%\Documents\01_Scripts\Hotkeys_1.ahk'
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogOn
$Description='This task will keep ???'
$msg = 'Enter the username and password that will run the task';
$credential = $Host.UI.PromptForCredential('Task username and password',$msg,'COMPUTERNAME\USERNAME',$env:userdomain)
$username = $credential.UserName
$password = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
$settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -AllowStartIfOnBatteries -DontStopIfGoingOnBatteries -StartWhenAvailable -DontStopOnIdleEnd
Try{
$ErrorActionPreference='stop'
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $jobname -Action $action `
-Trigger $trigger -RunLevel Highest -User $username -Password $password -Settings  $settings -Description $Description|Out-Null
}
Catch{
Write-Warning $_
}

$find=Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName '*Name of task*'
If($find){
Write-Host 'Task has been created sucessfully' -BackgroundColor DarkBlue
```

I'm stuck around this part specifically:

```
$credential = $Host.UI.PromptForCredential('Task username and password',$msg,'COMPUTERNAME\USERNAME',$env:userdomain)
```

Comment: You need to define "insert my password automatically". Are you trying to get rid of the prompt? Do you get any errors? Is the target user a local user account or a domain account?

Comment: Let me try again.

The script generates and lanches a pop up window.

It auto fills in the username box automatically with string text as I want.

The password field does not fill in any information and I have to manually input my password.

I want to automatically fill the password input box like I do the username input field.

I hope that makes better sense.

Thank you for responding.

Comment: Why the need for a popup to begin with if username/password already is known and not to be manually entered?

Comment: I just want to get better at scripting. I am like a lot of people on here and I love this stuff. On a practical side, to save time, On a security side, probably not a good idea.